# Smart pointers vs dumb pointers: polymorphism behavior oddity

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I was debugging an issue in some larger code and realized something strange about smart pointers and their polymorphic properties. This is best seen through the simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  virtual void who() {cout << "I am class A" << endl; };
}; 

class B : public A{
public:
  void who() {cout << "I am class B" << endl; };
}; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  B b;  
  A * aptr = &b;
  aptr->who(); //Output: I am class B

  B * bptr = &b;
  bptr->who(); //Output: I am class B

  shared_ptr<A> sptr;
  sptr = make_shared<A>(b);
  sptr->who(); //Output: I am class A

  sptr = make_shared<B>(b);
  sptr->who(); //Output: I am class B

  return 0;
}
```

The first two outputs makes sense to me, but why can I access the member function defined in  A (see the third output) when the only object I have initialized is of type B? In some sense, this is a nice trick for accessing members of the base class of an object of derived type. However, this still feels a bit spooky to me...

Can anyone explain why this behavior is possible with smart pointers but not regular pointers?

Comment: The seconds `aptr->who();` line should be `bptr->who();`

Comment: And if you actually want to "access members of the base class of an object of derived type", you just do `sptr->A::who()`.

Comment: Fixed that typo, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::make_shared` always creates a brand new object.  That is,

```
sptr = make_shared<A>(b);
```

is more like

```
A* p1 = new A(b);
```

and not like

```
A* p2 = &b;
```

`p1` and the return value of `make_shared` do not point at `b` at all.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Not so spooky after all!

Answer (score 4):

The following statement:

```
sptr = make_shared<A>(b);
```

is basically the same as:

```
sptr = shared_ptr(new A(b));
```

Instead of creating a shared_ptr from a pointer to `B`, you are creating a new `A` object with the copy constructor of `A`.

Answer (score 4):

`make_shared<A>(b)` uses `b` to construct an object of type `A`, and points to that newly constructed object. This slices the `B` object, so the `shared_ptr` truly points to an `A`.